# DateTimePicker value not regarded when updating datagridview to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview, datetimepicker

I have a datagridview which is bound to a SQL Server table. I update the changes by clicking on a button like this:

```
SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * From EDI;", conn.ConnectionString);
SqlCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);
dataAdapter.UpdateCommand = cb.GetUpdateCommand();                 
dataAdapter.Update(dataSet, "EDI");
```

In my datagridview the cell values of a certain column can be changed by selecting a date of a datetimepicker. So on the datetimepicker_value changed event the code looks like this:

```
private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString();
        dateTimePicker1.Visible = false;           
}
```

The problem now is, that the update works very well, but not for this datecolumn. The funny thing is, that the update of the datecolumn works, if I change the value of the datetimpicker *twice* and update after that.

I'm pretty desperate right now and thank you for an answer in advance

Comment: Have a look at the datatable behind the datagrid view, to make sure the data is being set there?

Comment: Sorry guys,

I really spent hours, but now I found the solution myself. I had to add
    bindingSource.EndEdit();
Now it works.

Thanks anyways

Comment: You can now add it as an answer and accept it. This will help other users looking for same kind of help.